# Load external content in div & manipulate dom

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe, cross-domain

What i want is to load external content ( from different domain name ) into a div and manipulate dom of this external loaded content.
For exemple i load in a div bbc.com and i want to be able to select all the "a" tag link in this page.
Here is a exemple i have done in [jscribble](http://jsfiddle.net/eMNfd/80/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#wrap').contents().find('iframe').mouseenter(function() {
    $('a').hide();
});  
});
```

In this JScribble, i have just try to make the "a" tag react using .hide() function in order to see if the 'tag' is found. but it seems that its not found because of the cross-domain security.

So i'm not sure anymore that the iframe is the solution.

Is there any other way to load an external content inside a div and manipulate dom ? ( external content have a different domain name )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to use manipulation with cross domain,you need to call iframe contents to your domain name ...

if your file is html then you should try this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).ready(function($) {
        var tmp = $('#wrap iframe').contents().find('html').mouseenter(function() {
        $('a').hide();
    });  
               // alert(tmp); use for debugging
            });
    });
```

when mouse enters to anchor tag that will be disappear (hide)! same you can do when mouse exits you can show it back...

Comment: It still doesn't work....  it seems that it doesn't work.. here is the thing i've tried : http://www.nathaliedupasquier.fr/Load_2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform manipulations with a cross domain iframe because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). What you can do is to fetch the iframe content server side and serve it as coming from your own domain.

These links might help [cors](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/),[phantom](http://phantomjs.org)